# Redux WP framework, any way to create logical options inside options panel?

Tags: wordpress, frameworks

I'm playing with redux wp framework, its easy and really usefull, but I'm reaching a limitation (probably caused by me): if I use, [for example](http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/fields/multi_text/)

```
'type'      => 'multi_text'
```

is there any way to dynamically add, for example, checkboxes for each added text? I mean, somehow, acces this option (or any other) get values and play with them, not from otside but inside options panel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize Redux Framework to meet your requirement. Lets take and example:

Create new field that adds both text and check-box as below:

```
'type'      => 'multi_text_check'
```

In the `../inc/fields` folder of Redux Framework find `multi_text` folder, copy it and rename it to `multi_text_check`.

In `field_multi_text.php` of that folder add field for check-box.

Comment: See the comment below. I had an issue signing into stack exchange. Hehe.

Comment: Where is the comment?

Answer (score 0):

Lead developer of Redux here. What you need to do is build your own field/extension. This will allow you to customize any extension without altering the Redux core.

You will find the details for this (including a boilerplate repo) here: http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/advanced/loading-extensions/

Good luck.